# Flutter Provider Weird Split Method Error When Navigating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

So I am using the Provider Package in my Flutter app and everything is going well until I closed my project in VSCode and reopened it with the same exact code and then I try to navigate to a new page using this method :

```
  void _goToTheSettingsPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: SettingsProvider(),
          child: SettingsPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and the SettingsPage is code is very simple :

```
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppLocalizations appLocalizations = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    BibleDatabase bibleDatabase = Provider.of<BibleDatabase>(context);
    SettingsProvider settingsProvider = Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context);
    int selectedTool = Provider.of<int>(context);
    Color selectedColor = HelperMethods.getColorFromNumber(selectedTool);
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      // Normal UI Widgets Here
    )
  }
}
```

and those are the providers I have put in the start of the Material App :

```
[
      StreamProvider<double>(
        builder: (context) => bibleDatabase.preferredFontSizeController.stream,
      ),
      StreamProvider<int>(
        builder: (context) => bibleDatabase.selectedToolController.stream,
      )
];
```

while bibleDatabase is just a value coming from a normal Provider.value() object...

so why I am getting this weird error??

```
I/flutter ( 8624): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8624): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SettingsPage(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter ( 8624): [InheritedProvider<SettingsProvider>, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#d8deb], MediaQuery,
I/flutter ( 8624): InheritedProvider<BibleDatabase>, InheritedProvider<int>]):
I/flutter ( 8624): The method 'split' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 8624): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 8624): Tried calling: split(".")
I/flutter ( 8624): User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 8624):   ChangeNotifierProvider<SettingsProvider>
I/flutter ( 8624):   
lib\pages\bible_page.dart:75
I/flutter ( 8624): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8624): #0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 8624): #1      AppLocalizations._resolve 
package:easy_localization/easy_localization_delegate.dart:84
I/flutter ( 8624): #2      AppLocalizations.tr 
package:easy_localization/easy_localization_delegate.dart:62
I/flutter ( 8624): #3      SettingsPage.build 
package:christy/pages/settings_page.dart:48
I/flutter ( 8624): #4      StatelessElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4001
I/flutter ( 8624): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3933
I/flutter ( 8624): #6      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #8      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #9      Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #10     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #12     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #14     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #15     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #16     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #18     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #19     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #20     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4080
I/flutter ( 8624): #21     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #22     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #23     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5119
I/flutter ( 8624): #25     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #26     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #27     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #28     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #29     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #30     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #31     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #32     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #33     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5119
I/flutter ( 8624): #34     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #35     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5119
I/flutter ( 8624): #37     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #38     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #39     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5119
I/flutter ( 8624): #40     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #41     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5119
I/flutter ( 8624): #43     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #44     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #45     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #46     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #47     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #48     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4080
I/flutter ( 8624): #49     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #50     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #51     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #52     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #53     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #54     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #55     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #56     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #57     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #58     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #59     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #60     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #68     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #69     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #70     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #71     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #72     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #73     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #74     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5119
I/flutter ( 8624): #75     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #76     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #77     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #78     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #79     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #80     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4080
I/flutter ( 8624): #81     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #82     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #83     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #84     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #92     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #93     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #94     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #95     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #96     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #97     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #98     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #99     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #100    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #101    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #102    StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4080
I/flutter ( 8624): #103    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #104    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #105    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #106    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #107    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #108    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3916
I/flutter ( 8624): #109    StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4080
I/flutter ( 8624): #110    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter ( 8624): #111    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter ( 8624): #112    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter ( 8624): #113    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4902
I/flutter ( 8624): #114    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5235
I/flutter ( 8624): #115    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #116    _TheatreElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/overlay.dart:607
I/flutter ( 8624): #117    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #118    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #119    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #120    StatefulElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4112
I/flutter ( 8624): #121    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #122    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #123    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #124    ProxyElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4246
I/flutter ( 8624): #125    _InheritedNotifierElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:94
I/flutter ( 8624): #126    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #127    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5126
I/flutter ( 8624): #128    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #129    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #130    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #131    StatefulElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4112
I/flutter ( 8624): #132    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #133    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5126
I/flutter ( 8624): #134    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #135    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5126
I/flutter ( 8624): #136    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2885
I/flutter ( 8624): #137    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3953
I/flutter ( 8624): #138    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3730
I/flutter ( 8624): #139    BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2340
I/flutter ( 8624): #140    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:701
I/flutter ( 8624): #141    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback 
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:285
I/flutter ( 8624): #142    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1033
I/flutter ( 8624): #143    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:975
I/flutter ( 8624): #144    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:891
I/flutter ( 8624): #148    _invoke  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:236:10)
I/flutter ( 8624): #149    _drawFrame  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:194:3)
I/flutter ( 8624): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 8624): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: The problem is `split` method called on null object in bible_page.dart file, please provide more codes in this snippet of codes.

Comment: `provider` doesn't call `split` even once. It has to be in your code somewhere

Comment: @ShadyBoshra Yes I know ... But the error said that it is coming from the ChangeNotifierProvider in the 4th line of the _goToTheSettingsPage method

Comment: @RémiRousselet nor I called it... The error is simply coming from the 4th line of the method

Comment: How you say that!! Your logs `ChangeNotifierProvider<SettingsProvider> lib\pages\bible_page.dart:75`, Where you are getting this information you said??

Comment: @ShadyBoshra bible_page.dart:75 is the 4th line of the _goToTheSettingsPage method I showed you... I don't get your question that much

Comment: @ShadyBoshra sorry I was a silly mistake ... Some package was calling split on a null string...

Comment: @RémiRousselet Sorry, it was a silly mistake not even related to the Provider Package

Comment: I knew it... :p

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this error. This error is because of Navigation. When you use Navigator.of(context).push then navigating page will become the child of the Material app and it will have no longer access to Provider.
See this Example::
[Widget Tree before navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TQXm.png)

if you see this I am having MaterialApp and to that, I am children of Provider of AuthRouter. I wanted AuthRouter to be available to the entire Tree.
When I Navigate from StudentHomePage the widget tree will become like this

[Widget Tree before navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDESV.png)

If you see My AuthRouter is no Longer a Child of the MaterialApp. So StudentDashboardPage is a new child and it doesn't have access to AuthRouter. so when I try to access AuthRouter from StudentDashboardPage It will show an error.

Solution 1:: Pass the provider objects to SettingsPage i.e dependency injection.
I hope it will work for you.

Solution 2:: Wrap Provider on top of MaterialApp